# Sum of values in array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I have an array like this :

```
   rez = array([
   array([1,2,3], dtype=object),
   array([4,5,6], dtype=object),
   array([7,8,9], dtype=object),
   ], dtype=object)
```

I want to sum each subarray to have a new array like this :

```
    rez2 = array([6, 15,24])
```

But when I use :

```
    numpy.sum(rez,axis = 1)
```

it doesn't work, cause "rez" is a one-dimensionnal array (?!). it doesn't make any sense for me ;)

How to do that, please ?

Comment: sum_array = [sum(x) for x in rez] should work.

Comment: I can successfully run your example with `rez.sum(1)`.

Comment: Thanks @MjZac but I forget to say that I'm not suppose to use a for loop.

I finally use : resultat = list(map(sum, rez)) and it works :)

Comment: @LilyZen Then `list(map(sum,rez))` could be the one.

Comment: @LilyZen The code you have posted actually works for me. Are you getting any errors while running your code? (You have used an additional `,` in the posted code)

Comment: @ Gautham M @trailing_whitespace the code I post is a simplification of my actual code... which one doesn't work with the "simple syntaxe". weird :)

Comment: @LilyZen could you post a simple example that causes an error for you?

Comment: your array definition might be incorrect. Please check my answer to see if ti works :)

Comment: You should be using a proper 2D Numpy array with a shape of (3, 3) for that data, with an appropriate Numpy numeric dtype. The `object` dtype is a convenience feature that allows you to make Numpy arrays of plain Python objects, but you don't get the usual Numpy speed & RAM usage benefits.

Comment: My array is generated by a function... I drop my files in GitHub (just in case you wanna have a look on the code) : https://github.com/LilyZen07/Monty_Hall_Game.git
I think @PM2Ring you may have right. I just start to learn Python so...I might define my array in a wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `numpy`, you probably need to **define the array as follows**:

```
rez = np.array([
   np.array([1,2,3], dtype=object),
   np.array([4,5,6], dtype=object),
   np.array([7,8,9], dtype=object),
   ], dtype=object)
```

After this, you can try:

```
rez2 = np.sum(rez,1)
print (rez2)
Out[13]: array([6, 15, 24], dtype=object)
```

or alternatively:

```
rez2 = rez.sum(1)
print (rez2)

Out[15]: array([6, 15, 24], dtype=object)
```

Both options work okay for me.

Comment: My array is generated by a function... I drop my files in GitHub (just in case you wanna have a look on the code) : github.com/LilyZen07/Monty_Hall_Game.git I think you may have right. I just start to learn Python so...I might define my array in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

rez = np.array(
    [
        np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object),
        np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype=object),
        np.array([7, 8, 9], dtype=object),  # no need for a ',' here
    ],
    dtype=object,
)
rez2 = np.array(np.sum(rez, axis=1))
```

Try this if you received a syntax error. Attaching screenshot of my code and result
[image]

Comment: [Trailing commas](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id29) are a part of valid syntax in Python. This should not cause an error in the OP's case.